# Avoiding a Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, extjs, undefined

When I run my code the console prints out an error message `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error`.  I thought an if statement would avoid this, but so far not luck. Here is my code

```
   if (records[0].get('StatusString') !== 'undefined') {
              creativeStatus = records[0].get('StatusString');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `array` is undefined it will fall over extend your if statement to the below

```
if (records && records[0] && records[0].get('StatusString') !== 'undefined') {
    creativeStatus = records[0].get('StatusString');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof (records && records[0] && records[0].get) !== 'undefined'){
   creativeStatus = records[0].get('StatusString');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

records[0] is undefined. Try putting the if check around that to catch the error.

```
if (records[0] !== 'undefined') {
  creativeStatus = records[0].get('StatusString');
}
```

Comment: whats happens if `records[0].get('StatusString');` is undefined it will set `creativeStatus` to a state he does not wants